# import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient; is not present error seen in java spring boot project

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am using spring parent version 2.4.5 and spring mongodb data module 3.1.8 version and this module internally uses 'mongodb-driver-core version 4.1.2' which seems to be the java mongo driver version being used by the dependency. My problem is I am trying to connect to mongo db cluster on my local using the latest spring boot version and my project uses maven but my intelliJ and eclipse(tried in both) shows `import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;` as red meaning both the IDEs are not able to detect this class and find it.

Sharing Code snippet (for giving an idea where the error is) that I am using to create the mongotemplate bean
`@Bean public MongoClientFactoryBean getMongoFactoryBean(){ return new MongoClientFactoryBean();}`

`@Bean public MongoTemplate getTemplate(MongoClientFactoryBean factory){ return new MongoTemplate(factory.getObject(), "some database name")}`

I get an error in above method while doing a build `java cannot access com.mongodb.client.MongoClient class file for com.mongodb.client.MongoClient not found`

Any Idea what is going wrong here and any suggestions to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have the `MongoDB`  dependency on your pom file? I am supposing you use maven...

Comment: You are using spring boot, and use `Spring Data MongoDB`. You dont need MongoClient So you dont need to make any beans. You can extend MOngoRepository with your repository to do the CRUD. If you need additional work like aggregation , just call  `@Autowired MonogTempleate mt;` in service layer and do your operations like `mt.update()` Eg: https://www.split.io/blog/crud-spring-boot-mongodb/

Comment: Assuming that you are using Maven I would guess that it has corrupted the Mongo Driver jar when it downloaded it. Try clearing out your local Maven cache and rebuilding your app.